# fnmatch.fnmatch() not detecting correct file (or detecting none at all)

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

Given a file called **SI 01130 TN 72 - 2016-02-19** in the current working directory, and the following:

```
import os
import fnmatch

def matching_current_instruction_id_in_baseline(_id):
    for _file in os.listdir('.'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(_file, 'SI 01130 TN 72*'):
            return file
        else:
            continue
    return None
```

why doesn't the following pick it up (all it matches is a file called 'x', for some reason).

```
In[50]: matching_current_instruction_id_in_baseline('SI 01130 TN 72')
Out[50]: 'x
```

Comment: Not an answer but glob would be a better approach, in particular iglob if you just want to see if there is any match, your else  continue is also redundant.  fnmatch would also match the string  as posted so there is something else going on.

Comment: `return next(glob.iglob("path_to/'SI 01130 TN 72*'"),None)` will do all that your current function is.

Comment: You are working with a variable called `_file` but then return `file`. After fixing that, it works for me.

Comment: @jsfan Eyes of the hawk, speed of the puma.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham An elegant one-liner indeed, thank you.

Comment: No worries, I would love to know how you get `'x` as output, there is a typo in my previous comment also the inner questoes should not be there

Comment: I'm sure that was just for testing, but I suspect the `fnmatch()` call should be using `_id`. Otherwise, it is rather pointless to pass an argument to `matching_current_instruction_id_in_baseline()`.

Comment: @jsfan Yep it was just for testing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate and test `_file`, but return `file`, which happens to be a built-in function in Python 2. Not sure why it prints `'x`, but that's why you don't see what you expect.